# FFMPEG: “DLL amfrt64.dll failed to open” on Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch-file, h.264

I experienced the following issue.

I'm using ffmpeg to batch resize/compress photos and videos on Windows 10. I used a version 3 and since upgraded to ver 4.4 of ffmpeg the quality of outputs dropped. I found out that I need to modify my script and explicitly define the output encoder, however when defining h264 I always got this error

```
DLL amfrt64.dll failed to open
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to update you also with a solution I found. It appears that ffmpeg (Windows build) has few h264 options compiled. check this out:

```
ffmpeg.exe -encoders | find "264"
<cut>
 V..... libx264              libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (codec h264)
 V..... libx264rgb           libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 RGB (codec h264)
 V..... h264_amf             AMD AMF H.264 Encoder (codec h264)
 V..... h264_nvenc           NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
 V..... h264_qsv             H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration) (codec h264)
 V..... nvenc                NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
 V..... nvenc_h264           NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
```

Therefore, if you type only "h264" it'll assume the first listed option, which is the one for AMD. If you're not running AMD CPU, you'll most probably get this error.

the solution is to define the right codec version, as named in ffmpeg. For me it was:

```
ffmpeg4.4 -i input.mp4 -codec:v h264_qsv output.mp4
```

Mind that you may also get other DLL error messages like

```
Cannot load nvcuda.dll
```

It all depends which codec name you'll use and what platform you run (Intel, AMD, NVIDIA). Mind also that for encoding you can use also these codec which are listed as "encoder", e.g. libx264 in the list above didn't work for me for encoding.

Comment: “If you're not running AMD CPU …” - This statement doesn’t make sense.  Windows 10 only runs on x86 hardware.  Any software that supports an AMD processor supports Intel processors.

Comment: It's not about general compatibility but about the specific encoders which are created to use the hardware features (like graphical accelerators) of specific products like AMD or NVIDIA. Most probably you'd be able to install AMD AMF environment while running Intel processor and most probably you'd then NOT get the error I mentioned. But what's the point? when you can simply use a proper encoder as given by FFMPEG developers.